# Evaluating the significance of a GAM

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, gam

Can someone please help me interpret GAM p-values and significance? In a linear regression analysis a predictive variable may have an insignificant p-value, and yet still, be used for predictive purposes if the p-value of the entire model is significant. What do we do when p-values of predictive variables are insignificant in a GAM? I have run the model in R and gained the following output when running summary() and check.gam() on my model purchase ~ s(n_acts) + s(bal_crdt_ratio) + s(avg_prem_balance) + s(avg_fin_balance) + s(retail_crdt_ratio) + s(mortgage_age) + s(cred_limit)

Please follow the link below for my R output

[GAM summary() and gam.check()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzqee.png)

Comment: See `help("gam")`: "select: If this is TRUE then gam can add an extra penalty to each term so that it can be penalized to zero. This means that the smoothing parameter estimation that is part of fitting can completely remove terms from the model. If the corresponding smoothing parameter is estimated as zero then the extra penalty has no effect. Use gamma to increase level of penalization."

Comment: That helped, thank you very much!